# How to get the height of a fixed positionned div? (and push following content)

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-position

I'm trying to create a template for a wordpress blog.

The thing is I'm trying to put an image as fullscreen background, but without using the background css function *background-image {}* as I can't retrieve the thumbnail image of a post in the css code.

So, I display my image as *position: fixed; z-index: 1*.
I complete the code with a *width: 100%;* and a *height: auto;* in order to make the image fit with the screen size (which is quite wrong if the screen is not the same ratio as the image...).

Then I display my footer which can have a dynamic height. For this case I'm using a flexbox for the whole page.

My concerns are :
The background image can have different ratios and I want it to fullfill the viewport no matter what, but not overflow it.

Real problem is that because I have a *position: fixed* I can't get the image's *height*, which means I can't push dynamically the footer.

One solution would be to duplicate the image div and give it a *visibility: hidden* so I would have the exact size of the background image and push the footer. But I consider this solution as inelegant. And I'm convinced that it must use ressources... Well, I'm just not confortable with duplicating content even if it does not appear.

Here are screenshots and a video of the problem, followed by some code :

[Screenshot 1](http://extatic.net/wp-content/uploads/perso/extatic2.png)

[Video of the concern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZldYVMj7ZQ&feature=youtu.be)

HTML

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="single.php">
  <?php include("menu.php"); ?>
  <section id="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <?php if(have_posts()) :?>
        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="postThumbnail">
          <?php
              if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                  the_post_thumbnail();
              }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
          <div class="col-1-1">             
              <div id="postMetadata">
                <div id="postTitle">
                  <h2>
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                  </h2>
                </div>
                <div id="postCategory">
                  <p>
                    <?php
                    $category = get_the_category();
                    echo $category[0]->slug;
                  ?>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div id="postDate">
                  <p>
                    <?php the_time("d F") ?>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="postContent" >
                <?php the_content(); ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
      </div>
  </section>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

CSS

```
/* ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- */
/* html */

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}

/* ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- */
/* body */

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 640px;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Open Sans, Arial;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
}

/* ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- */
/* header */

header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999; /* do not remove = header always on top of content */
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 8px;
}

    header:hover {
        transition: all 1s ease;
        box-shadow: rgb(40, 40, 40) 0px 0px 12px;
    }

#headerMenu {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 48px;
    margin: 0 32px 0 32px;
}


#siteLogo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 48px;
}

    #siteLogo a img {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
    }

    #siteLogo a h1 {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        letter-spacing: 0.3em;
        color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }


#searchEngine {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 0;
}

#searchForm input {
    position: relative;
    width: 164px;
    height: 32px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 32px 0 0;
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: none;
    transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

    #searchForm input:focus {
        width: 226px;
    }

#index\.php #searchForm input:focus {
    width: 226px;
}

#search\.php #searchForm input {
    transition: width 0.5s ease;
    animation-name: searchFormResize;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}

@keyframes searchFormResize {
    from {
        width: 226px;
    }

    to {
        width: 164px;
    }
}

/* ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- */
/* footer */

footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 998;
}

    footer, footer a {
        color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        line-height: 2em;
    }

#twitter {
    background: rgb(99, 185, 251);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(99, 185, 251)0%,rgb(56, 110, 151) 100%);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    box-shadow: rgb(99, 185, 251) 0 0 4px;
}

    #twitter:hover {
        transition: all 1s ease;
        box-shadow: rgb(99, 185, 251) 0 0 8px;
    }

    #twitter .twitterTimeline {
        width: 520px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 32px 0 24px 0;
    }

    #twitter #twitterIcon {
        display: block;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        margin: 0 auto 16px auto;
    }

    #twitter #lastTweet {
        min-height: 90px;
    }

#infoFooter {
    padding: 16px 0 16px 0;
    background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(40, 40, 40) 0%,rgb(0, 0, 0) 100%);
    transition: all 1s ease;
    box-shadow: rgb(40, 40, 40) 0 0 8px;
}

    #infoFooter:hover {
        transition: all 1s ease;
        box-shadow: rgb(40, 40, 40) 0 0 12px;
    }

#siteMap {
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

    #siteMap li a {
        color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
    }

    #siteMap h3, #siteMap #iconHeart, #siteMap #iconContact, #siteMap #iconCategories {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #siteMap #iconHeart, #siteMap #iconContact, #siteMap #iconCategories {
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        position: relative;
        left: 8px;
        top: 1px;
    }

#copyright {
    padding: 16px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 0.7em;
}

    #copyright p {
        color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
        text-align: center;
    }

    #copyright a {
        color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
    }

    #copyright #siteName {
        letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    }

/* ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- */
/* misc */

#index\.php,
#single\.php,
#page\.php,
#search\.php,
#\404\.php {
    flex: 1;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    margin: 48px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 997;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
}

.col { /* /!\ must not have width setting*/
    display: block;
    max-width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 16px 0 16px;
}

.col-1-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(100% - 32px);
    margin: 0 16px 0 16px;
}

.col-1-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: calc(50% - 32px);
    margin: 0 16px 0 16px;
}

.col-1-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 32px);
    margin: 0 16px 0 16px;
}

.col-2-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: calc(((100% / 3) * 2) - 32px);
    margin: 0 16px 0 16px;
}

.col-1-4 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: calc(25% - 32px);
    margin: 0 16px 0 16px;
}

.col-2-4 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: calc(50% - 32px);
    margin: 0 16px 0 16px;
}

.col-3-4 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: calc(75% - 32px);
    margin: 0 16px 0 16px;
}

/* ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- */
/* responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    #siteMap .col-1-3 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: calc(100% - 32px);
        margin: 0 16px 16px 16px;
    }
}

/* ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- */
/* single.php */

#single\.php .postThumbnail img {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}

#single\.php, #single\.php #content {
    min-height: 100%;
}

    #single\.php #postMetadata {
    }

    #single\.php #postContent {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options which you can achieve doing a full screen background.

**Option 1:**

You pull the image out into the header into a `<style>` tag and use the `background-size:cover;`

```
$url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
```

That will get your thumbnail post in the header. However you can do it inline and get the thumbnail there.

**Option 2:**

The second option is to use javascript to resize the image and make it work. I would use:

http://johnpolacek.github.io/imagefill.js/

And apply it to a full width/height div. It will position the image absolute and work well. Hope you get this sorted.

Comment: Hi Andy and thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately, I don't want to mess around and as I'm not a developer.

And I don't want to put the image in background as I need it's height to puch the content + footer after.

Basically, an image's height can be less than the viewport's height, so I need a div which is perfectly the size of the fixed div to push the content after.

But the second option might be a part of the solution.

Comment: In theory you don't need to use the image height to make the footer sticky.  This tutorial shows you how. http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: It's not really about a sticky footer.
Maybe I was really unclear about what I intend to do :

I want to display an image, which is fixed.
Then, after the image, no matter what height is the image, I want to have some text.

But after the image. Which is difficult here, because a fixed image has no physical height.

It's kind of a parallax effect : content that scrolls over the fixed image.
But I want to make it only in CSS, with an image that can respect the width size of the viewport.

Comment: I nearly did what I intended to do. [http://extatic.net](http://extatic.net) Just click any article and see by yourself.

But I have - at least - one more concern.

The white-backgrounded div which displays the text/content must be at list the height (min-height) of the screen, minus the height of the footer so the content covers entirely the background image.

Any idea?